# Anyone successfully installed .net framework 4.0 Beta2 on Windows 7 (64 bit)?

Tags: .net, windows-7, .net-4.0, windows-7-x64

I've just installed windows 7 (64 bit) and sql server 2008 with sp1. Everything seemed fine until now. I've now downloaded .net Framework 4 beta 2 and am trying to run the installer and i get "unable to create new files in the folder into which files are being extracted." Can any one tell me what i'm missing? Has anyone been successful with the 64 version of windows 7 and .net Framework 4 Beta 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and found this blog post: http://blog.seancleaver.com/sean_cleaver/2009/10/installing-visual-studio-2010-beta-2-on-mac-book-pro.html

This one solved my problem, maybe you can solve it as well.

cheers

Comment: Thank you, thank you thank you! Seriously man, MUCH appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Installed RTM a couple weeks back and installed the Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 Super-Ultimate-Enterprise edition and it went flawlessly.  Perhaps you could try getting the framework through one of the Visual Studio edition installers?

Comment: Ive tried to download and run Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 but it bombs on the Framework 4 install. It says access denied if i look at the log.

Comment: Very odd.  Is there anything in the Application or System log that has a hint about what's going on?